How to access origin/main in gitlab CI/CD
I added some automated commit quality checks to our gitlab CI, which essentially walks through all the commits that are in the merge request one-by-one. I essentially loop through the result of a git rev-list origin/main..
Unfortunately, the runner only doesn't directly clone the repo, leaving us without any of the refs needed to pull this off. Our current workaround is allowing the CI access to the ${GITLAB_PROJECT_ACCESS_TOKEN} which requires an extra setting on the repository and also allows push access.
This is the gist of it:
    - git remote set-url origin "https://gitlab-ci-token:${GITLAB_PROJECT_ACCESS_TOKEN}@${CI_SERVER_HOST}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}.git"
    - git fetch --all
    - git rev-list --reverse origin/${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME}..

Is there a way to tell GitLab to just do this for me? Clone the repository in a way that has the tags and remote refs available as they would be locally, but not give push access to the things running in the CI?

The answer was more simple than I thought. The git remote set-url part is actually completely unneeded and one can run git fetch --all simply.
Note, that it is also possible to set extra flags to how gitlab fetches by default.
Example from the documentation:
variables:
  GIT_FETCH_EXTRA_FLAGS: --prune
script:
  - ls -al cache/

but the --all flag cannot be passed here, since the extra flags are basically passed to git fetch origin $REFSPECS --depth 50 (the above example translates to git fetch origin $REFSPECS --depth 50  --prune) and it's not possible to set --all if a refspec has already been passed to git fetch.

You can configure the GitLab runner to clone the project on each run.
In your project go to Settings -> CI/CD -> General Pipelines -> Git strategy and choose "git clone".
Note, however, that this may slow your pipelines down compared to the "git fetch" strategy. A more fine-grained approach is to configure this using the GIT_STRATEGY environment variable only for the jobs that need it.
E.g.:
some_job:
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: clone
  script:
    - sh ./scripts/do_my_special_ci.sh


Thanks, this actually pointed me towards some documentation and it turns out that for purposes of fetching, the remote is already set up properly so you can just do git fetch --all.
